# Generic way to call graphAPI from reactjs apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

Need help with creating a generic function which can be used to call Graphql API from react-apollo.
Learn about the following ways 
using  componenet
graphql(gql`query{...}`) method
using axios lib

any suggestion how can I create a generic function or common function that can be used.

Answer (score -1):

using axios library.

```
const  graphqlfetchhandler = async (query, variables) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      endpointURL,
      {
        query: gitQuery,
        variables: variables
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "token YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```